# Represent JavaScript code as string

Tags: javascript, eval

I have the following piece of code (pseudo-code):

```
$(function() { 
    var a = 'Hello world';
    var api = Function;
    api.start = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    };
});
```

I want to send it back to the user through JSON object (e.g. `code` property) and then execute it with `eval`.

How can I escape that piece of  code to be used later by `eval` function?

Comment: Isn't this code already a string ?

Comment: That's generally a very bad idea.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Perhaps you should look at getting the script via jsonp.

Comment: But let's back up and understand the larger requirement. What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: @dystroy — No, it's a function call being passed a function as an argument.

Comment: It's almost always a better idea to set up your scripts on the client in advance and then pass back JSON data that triggers them (e.g. by using `switch` on a property of the JSON to determine which function to call). I've never seen a situation where there is so much and so variable code that it is worth sending it on demand.

Comment: I am working on Chrome extension and I am trying to add extra layer of protection. The user enters a key, then request is sent to the processing page, if key is valid the code is sent back to the user.

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with Chrome extensions, but why not just have the function on the client, and send the data it needs?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to *really* trust the code coming back to allow this:

```
var myObj = {
    trustMe: "(function() { var a = 'Hello world'; alert(a);}());"
};

eval(myObj.trustMe);
```

If instead you passed back your data, you could keep all the code separated from your object...

```
var myObj = {
    justData: "Hello world;"
};

alert(myObj.justData);
```

I have used a JavaScript object, but the idea is the same if you are sending back JSON, you just put the string as a property value.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll assume you have valid reasons for doing this. Second, assuming you want to use Java; you might call [StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson(String)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJson%28java.lang.String%29); once escaped your code should look something like

```
"$(function() {\n\tvar a = 'Hello world';\n" 
    + "\tvar api = Function;\n\tapi.start = function(e) {\n"
    + "\t\te.preventDefault();\n\t};});"
```